# What these seals characters means? (Characters identified: 讀書志在聖賢 爲官心存君國)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I have this seal but i really dont know what means these characters,
If somebody can help me to translate i would appreciate.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't explain it in a short sentence, but I found this translation from a [blog](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_4a517e8b0102x0ox.html).

It seems that the blogger loves ancient Chinese literature.

He translate it to

**In learning, aim at the sages; as an official, be loyal to sovereign and country.**

Anyway it advocates abandoning your personal profit.