# Two Large (2x2x2) Stone Seals needing transcription (Characters identified: 志在聖賢 爲官心存)

Tags: character-identification, seal, transcription

[image]

[image]
Large Stone Seals needing transcription

Comment: See also: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/41951